# Mongoose - Running query in a require leaves _id out

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I spent a long time trying to return `_id` for my results. I still don't understand why when the query is wrapped in a function and then required why it doesn't return the `_id`

**Results without _id**

```
api.User.js

module.exports = {
    getAll: function(passData){
        return User.find({}).execAsync()
            .then(function(data){
                console.info(data); //Outputs everything other than the _id
                passData.userDetails = data;
                return passData;
            });
    }
}
```

**Results with _id**

```
users.js

var api = require('../../api/api.User');
module.exports = function(app) {
    var controllers = {
        home: function (req, res) {
            var passData = {};
            User.find({}).execAsync()
                .then(function(data){
                    console.info(data); //Outputs _id as you would expect!!
                });

            api.getAll(passData) //Calling the api.User.js and not returning the _id's
                .then(function (passData) {
                    res.render('admin/users', {
                        user: req.user,
                        title: 'Admin Users',
                        selectedAdminMenu: 'users',
                        passData: passData
                    });
                })
                .catch(console.log.bind(console));
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you specified another id in schema model ?

Comment: Nope, as I said. Maybe not obviously enough :p Is that when I get the results in `user.js` with directly referencing `User` in the file and not from a `require` I get back the `_id` as an `ObjectId()`

Comment: I have no ideea, have you tried specifically `.select('_id')` ?

Comment: And I've found an issue on the github repo that might help, or not: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3378

Comment: Can you replicate this in straight code that reproduces the problem without express and whatever promisification you're using?